# How to speed up sending mail via Amazon SES?

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Sending half a million emails takes too long: 6 to 8 hours. Quota allows 90 emails per second. Sending from a dedicated server with nice performance, so memory/connection should not be the issue. Using batches of 50 emails at once.

Tryed varying number of emais in a batch: more than 50 causes CURL errors: seems like there's no response from Amazon to some of the threads. Even with 50 in a batch and a 1200ms pause between batches each mailout gets several hiccups.

So an average batch of 50 take from 4 to 6 s to complete + 1.2s pause — quite a long for 500k daily mailout.

Please advice how to tune the mailing to get its speed closer to the 90 mails/s.

Comment: 90 mails/sec and average supported mail send throughput not necessary related things. Checking with Amazon on supported throughput (i.e. per hour) and recommended approaches may be good idea.

Comment: Single batch of 90 mails goes out normally. Its the 'production' mode where the problems arise.

Comment: I'm having the same problem :( I plan to send 1 million email. I wrote a script using PHPMailer to send to SES. I tested with 5 emails and it took 10 seconds! When I turned on the debug mode I found that everytime an email was sent PHPMailer repeated the same process: open a connection with Amazon SES, authenticate, send email content and receive the sending result. It would be quicker if we can open connection and authenticate once for all, then close. I'm not sure if this is your case. What do you use to send emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about running several jobs in parallel? That way the potential damage from each cURL error is lessened. Start with two jobs, where each has its pauses and limits adjusted accordingly.

You should also make sure you're setting the cURL timeouts. Configure CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT and CURLOPT_TIMEOUT at the very least.